# readfile php function outputs extra digits at the end of URL

Tags: php

I'm using [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to echo the result of a `php` file on another server. The result is always a `.xml` `URL`.

It almost work's... But the problem is that at the end of each `URL`, it ads to digits.

**Here's and example of my php code:**

```
echo $fcontents = readfile('https://example.com/xml/random-url.php'); echo $fcontents;
```

**And here's and example of the output result:**

```
https://example.xml44
```

Any idea on what might be the problem?

Comment: If you check the manual you provided, you'll see that `readfile` does not return the contents of the file but the number of bytes read or `false`. If you actually want to act on the contents, you probably want [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: @Yoshi  any way to remove those numbers after the `.xml`?

Comment: Yes, simply don't `echo` them. You don't need `echo` here at all, as `readfile` already outputs the contents of the read file.